How to count the number and proportion of different barcode combinations in DNA sequencing results
This question was also asked on Biostars
We used a new single-cell sequencing method for sequencing, and now we have encountered the following problems when analyzing the data. We designed three sequencing barcodes to be linked step by step. Specifically, we first linked the first barcode (containing 30 different base sequences), then linked the second barcode (containing 185 different base sequences) on this basis, and then linked the third barcode (containing 56 base sequences) on this basis.
The data obtained in an ideal state should be:

barcode1 sequence + barcode2 sequence + barcode3 sequence + DNA fragment + barcode3 reverse complementary sequence + barcode2 reverse complementary sequence + barcode1 reverse complementary sequence

There will be 3018556 Barcodes combinations.
But the actual sequencing data we analyzed is:

barcode1 sequence + barcode2 sequence + barcode3 sequence + DNA fragment + barcode3 reverse complementary sequence
barcode1 sequence + barcode2 sequence + barcode3 sequence + DNA fragment + barcode3 reverse complementary sequence + barcode2 reverse complementary sequence
barcode1 sequence + DNA fragment + barcode3 reverse complementary sequence + barcode2 reverse complementary sequence + barcode1 reverse complementary sequence
Sequence from unknown source + barcode1 sequence + barcode2 sequence + barcode3 sequence + DNA fragment + barcode3 reverse complementary sequence
barcode1 sequence + DNA fragment + sequence from unknown source
Sequence with one base difference from barcode1 sequence (maybe caused by mutation?) + DNA fragment + barcode3 reverse complementary sequence + barcode2 reverse complementary sequence + barcode1 reverse complementary sequence

The above are just some examples, there are actually many combinations. In addition, all sequences must contain barcode1 sequence or the reverse complementary sequence of barcode1 sequence.
We want to know the number and proportion of different barcode combinations. This problem has troubled me for a long time. I hope you can give me some code ideas to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

How were these reads sequenced? It seems too long to be able to capture all of this in a single Illumina short read. Please show example read sequences that demonstrate your problem; it will help greatly for us to understand what's going on.
